# Is there a RedBeanPHP equivalent for Python?

Tags: php, python, mysql, orm, redbean

When I say 'equivalent', I mean an ORM that allows for the same work-style. That is;

- Setting up a database
- Dispensing and editing 'beans' (table rows) as if the table was already ready, while the table is being created behind the scenes
- Reviewing, indexing and polishing the table structure before production

Thanks for any leads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, there is a proof-of-concept called `PyBean` as answered by Gabor de Mooij, but it barely offers any features and cannot be used. There are no other Python libraries that work like PyBean.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's called PyBean and you can find it here:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pybean

from the website:

> PyBean is intended as a proof-of-concept of a Python RedBeanPHP
>   implementation (see http://www.redbeanphp.com/ for the original
>   concept).

Comment: Unfortunately it's just a pre-alpha proof of concept. It doesn't even support MySQL yet

Comment: The project moved here and is currently for SQLite only https://github.com/jonathan-kosgei/pybean Hasn't really been updated in three years, though.